# Rest API to get different data

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, js

I have the following code to get values of a column.

```
function GetKPIS(EstruturaKPI){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "SITE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KPI')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + EstruturaKPI + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {

        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function(key, value){

            var UltimaData = (value.Data);


        })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

With this code, I am able to get the DATE the user has input into the field. The problem is, the date is shown in YYYY-MM-DDZ(time), and I wanted the date to show DD-MM-YYYY ONLY (Without the time).

How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: is your date column name Data?

Comment: @harshalgite yes. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code or use third-party js like [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to format dates.

```
function GetKPIS(EstruturaKPI){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "SITE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KPI')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + EstruturaKPI + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            jQuery.each(data.d.results, function(key, value){
                var date = new Date(value.Data); //assuming this is your date field
                var day = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
                var month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

                var UltimaData = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            })
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```